# How to implement SDP in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, sdp

I am trying to find examples of using Session Descriptor Protocol (SDP) with C++ or C. Can you recommend some literature, or webpages? I know about [RFC 4566](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4566.txt), but this specification is useless to me, because it doesn't have any examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try [openSIPS](http://www.opensips.org/), it's written in C.

Here is a
[hands-on book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0058C2MW4) you can buy from amazon.

Comment: Ok,thanks, but I am trying to find examples for Windows, and use Visual Studio.